# Search for a name in a csv file and return the entire row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to create a script to do the following:

1. Should be able to search for a name in a csv file.
2. Return entire row if match is found.

The CSV file looks like:

```
first_name,last_name,city   
James,Butt,New Orleans
John,Son,New York
Brenda,Harris,San Jose
```

If we search for James for example and return the entire row.

```
James Butt New Orleans
```

I tried the below code but it did not return an output.

There might be a way to do this using pandas and dataframes but I am not really confident with those.

Comment: You forgot the "below code"…

Comment: hi, I really don't know how to use pandas and dataframes. so, did not really forget any code

Comment: Then don't refer to it in your question because it looks like a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, load them into a dataframe and then filter:

**Code**

```py
df=pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv',sep=',')
print(df[df['first_name'] == 'James'])          #Searching by name 'James'
```

**Output**

```py
   first_name last_name city   
0  James      Butt      New Orleans
```